# Repeat request in RxMoya

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, moya

I'm using the latest version of Moya with RxSwift and I've encountered a logical issue for which I can't find a solution, at the moment.

Let's say that I have a UITableViewController with a ViewModel that implements the following interface:

```
protocol ListViewModelType {

    var items: Observable<[Item]> { get }

}
```

The `items` property is implemented as (using EVReflection):

```
var items: Observable<[Therapy]> {
        get {
            let provider = RxMoyaProvider<ItemService>()
            return provider
                .request(.all)
                .map(toArray: Item.self)
        }
    }
```

In the viewDidLoad method of the UITableViewController, I have set up a binding between the items property and the tableView via the following code:

```
self.viewModel.items
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier, cellType: cellType)) { row, element, cell in
                // cell configuration code
            }
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Now, I would like to refresh the content of the UITableView to reflect changes that the user has done through other parts of the app. Considering that the RxMoyaProvider returns an Observable, this should be easily done through another value emitted by the Observable, but I don't know how to communicate to the provider that it should refresh the content from the server and put it into the same Observable.

Am I missing something here? Is there a more recommended way to bind a UITableView to a list of objects coming from a RxMoyaProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload our Moya request. this is a bit hacky but i guess you get the hint.

```
let didAppear = Variable(true)
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    didAppear.value = true
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.didAppear.flatMap{ _ in self.viewModel.items}
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier, cellType: cellType)) { row, element, cell in
            // cell configuration code
        }
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

alternatively you could redesign our architecture with a offline-first principle

[image]

Comment: Ok, I see your point on the offline-first principle, but at the moment is outside the requirements and I'd prefer to stick to online-only. The method you're proposing seems a lot like a hack… Are you sure that there's no way to implement this using something else, like a wrapper for a MoyaProvider, maybe?

Comment: i really don't see a point to do that. Without the offline first

Comment: Well, the point would be to support situations where the answer of the server might change over time. Observables are described as streams of data and, IMHO, that's exactly what I have here: a stream of data that emits a new value every time I ask it to refresh.

Comment: yes but you need to ask it to refresh. that is this bit self.didAppear.flatMap{ _ in self.viewModel.items}

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just thought that maybe there was some sort of pre-designed method to do that. Anyway, just for reference, I'm discussing this on the Moya GitHub repo too, to see if we can find a more elegant solution, a little bit less "hacky" and, hopefully, integrated in Moya itself.

Comment: @MrAsterisco Could you point me to that discussion? Me too would like to see if there is a better way.